# Spring auto entity population from form

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using hibernate and spring mvc, I have a scenario where I have a Object A and a child object C. now for updating Entity A I use model object of spring mvc, this automatically populates all the keys from form with the object through reflection, except entity C.

What I am currently doing is:

1) adding a hidden varaible in form for foreign key,

2) explicitly fetching entity C.

3) setting entity C in Entity A.

4) updating entity A.

problem with above approach is, it has a security leak, I can change hidden variable by firebug. Secondly, even I ignore this security issue I need to fetch entity on my own and then have to set back again to object, which I suppose is a tedious task.

Are there any better ways of updating the whole object automatically via form/spring-from.

Comment: are you using http://www.springframework.org/tags/form in JSP along with commandName? If you use this JSTL in JSP you need not to make an object

Comment: yes u r right  in case there are no dependent objects, if there exist dependents then how to autofill in object ??